# Full-word selection in browser

Tags: javascript, cross-browser, selection

I understand that IE has a full-word selection feature, which people often want to turn off.

I want the opposite.

I want to automatically expand the selection to complete words in all browsers.  Actually, for the moment, I don't really care about IE (but I will eventually).

Anyone know of a solution for this?

Thanks.

Comment: "IE has a full-word selection feature" It does??

Comment: @NullUserException, I was going by this question, which is #1 in Google for "full-word selection."  I don't know (or care much) whether it's true. http://superuser.com/questions/28714/smart-word-selection-in-ie-how-to-disable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be able to do something in WebKit ([and apparently Firefox 4](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/selection/modify)) by using the modify method of the selection in conjunction with the `mousemove` event. It'll probably be quite tricky to get right though: you'll need to consider when it's appropriate to expand the selection.

Here's a very simple example of using the `modify` method:

```
<p>A paragraph with some nice text in it</p>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function expandSelection() {
        var sel;
        if (window.getSelection) {
            sel = window.getSelection();
            if (sel.modify) {
                sel.modify("extend", "forward", "word");
            }
        }
    }
</script>

<input type="button" onclick="expandSelection();" value="expand">
```

Comment: Thanks... this isn't as bad as I thought it would be.  It will be tricky to get exactly what I'm after, even where it's supported, but this looks like the best I can do for now.